# Is there any function for prefixing a character to a string and store in the same string?

Tags: c, concatenation, operators, c-strings, string-concatenation

how do we do the following operation in c?
s="#"+s;
where s is a string .

I've tried using strncat() but after concatenation answer should be stored in s with prefix "#.

Comment: Which you actually want, prefix or suffix?

Comment: prefixing the character "#" to a string s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `s` has enough elements, you can add a prefix of one character to `s` by:

1. Slide the existing string by one via [`memmove()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) (you cannot use `strcpy()` nor `memcpy()` because they don't support copying to overlapped region)
2. Write the character to add to the first element of `s`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int add_prefix(char* str, char c, size_t bufsz) {
    size_t strsize = strlen(str) + 1;

    if (bufsz <= strsize) {
        return -1;
    }

    memmove(str + 1, str, strsize); /* +1 for terminating null-character */
    str[0] = c;
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char s[128] = "hello";

    printf("before add_prefix() : %s\n", s);

    add_prefix(s, '#', sizeof(s));
    printf("after  add_prefix() : %s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the character array that stores the source string should be large enough to be able to append one more character.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[7] = "Hello";

    memmove( s + 1, s, strlen( s ) + 1 );
    s[0] = '#';

    puts( s );
}
```

The program output is

```
#Hello
```

A more general approach can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * append_prefix( char s[], const char *prefix )
{
    size_t n = strlen( prefix );

    if (n != 0)
    {
        memmove( s + n, s, strlen( s ) + 1 );
        memcpy( s, prefix, n );
    }

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[7] = "Hello";

    puts( append_prefix( s, "#" ) );
}
```

Using the function `append_prefix` you can append any string before another string provided that the result character array has enough space.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of depends on the application. If you are writing some string library, some search algorithm or other performance-critical stuff, then you can fiddle around with `memmove` as shown in other answers, or more likely some custom, alignment-based algorithm.

But unless you have such extreme RAM usage or performance requirements, then you should probably treat all strings as "immutable" (basically read-only) and just create a new one. Which is "good enough" for the average C application.

In which case it simply goes like:

```
char s[] = "hello";
char new_s [LARGE_ENOUGH] = "#";
strcat(new_s, s);
```

Where "LARGE_ENOUGH" could be something like `2 + strlen(s)`.

Comment: `#define LARGE_ENOUGH 640 /* 640 ought to be enough for any use :) */`

Comment: @pmg: https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/09/08/640k-enough/. Please read.